# Stan: output some (but not all) intermediate variables of interest

Tags: stan

I am a newcomer to Stan but quite a Stan enthusiast by now. Currently I am working on a Stan application involving a somewhat complex computation with a bunch of intermediate variables of which I would like to see one in the Stan output -- while trying to avoid adding too many of them to the output.

As far as I can tell I have two options (save for duplicating my code in the `generated quantities` which I'd like to avoid).

Option 1: put everything into `model` block and get no output.

```
...
model {
    real intermediatevar1; // local, not in output
    real intermediatevar2; // local, not in output
    real varofinterest; // local, not in output

    randvar1 ~ normal(...);
    ...
    randvarN ~ uniform(...);

    // complex operations including randvar1, ..., randvarN
    intermediatevar1 = ...
    intermediatevar2 = ...
    varofinterest = foo(intermediatevar2);

    y ~ normal(varofinterest, sigma);
}
...
```

Option 2: move computation into `transformed parameters` block and have everything in output.

```
...
transformed parameters {
    real intermediatevar1; // in output
    real intermediatevar2; // in output
    real varofinterest; // in output

    // complex operations including randvar1, ..., randvarN
    intermediatevar1 = ...
    intermediatevar2 = ...
    varofinterest = foo(intermediatevar2);
}
model {
    randvar1 ~ normal(...);
    ...
    randvarN ~ uniform(...);

    y ~ normal(varofinterest, sigma);
}
...
```

Is there a different way that let's me keep `varofinterest` in the output while not producing output for `intermediatevar1` etc. (the latter are vectors in my application and produce a lot of output)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer and comments were written in 2019, but the current version of PyStan is 3.3.0. PyStan 3.0 was released in 2021 and is compatibility-breaking with previous versions. This answer is probably out-of-date!*

Two options:

1. You can specify which variables to store when you fit the model. The API documentation explains how to do this.

   - In R, this is the `stan(pars=...)` argument; see  https://mc-stan.org/rstan/reference/stan.html
2. If you *never* want to save `intermediatevar1`, then just declare it locally. There are lots of examples of this pattern in the Stan language reference.

```
transformed parameters {
    real varofinterest; // in output
    {
        real intermediatevar1; // not in output
        real intermediatevar2; // not in output

        // complex operations including randvar1, ..., randvarN
        intermediatevar1 = ...
        intermediatevar2 = ...
        varofinterest = foo(intermediatevar2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should have read the Stan fitting output (pystan here):
``'pars' not specified. Showing first 10 parameters by default.``

Comment: I know this question is closed, but it happens to be the highest ranked search result for the query "Stan output some but not all intermediate variables", so I'd like to ask @sycorax for some clarification of item 1, i.e. where in the documentation is that found. I suspect (1) may depend on the Stan interface -- it might be available for some interfaces and not others.

Comment: @RobertDodier The portion of this answer about python APIs is probably out of date, because it was written in 2019.